# find the second highest frequency of the character in the string

Tags: c#, dictionary

I want to find the second highest frequency of the character in the string.
For example: abccddd

O/p should be : c

I tried with dictionary. I am storing everything in dictionary. Moreover, I am also sorting it. Now I dont know how should I proceed.

```
string input = tb_input.Text;
Dictionary<string, int> di = new Dictionary<string, int>();

for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    if (di.ContainsKey(input[i].ToString()))
    {
        int value = di[input[i].ToString()];               
        value++;

        di[input[i].ToString()] = value;
    }
    else
    {
        di.Add(input[i].ToString(), 0);
    }
}

var items = di.Values.ToList();

items.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToList();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're only storing number of occurrences in `items`. You should store character as well:

```
var items = di.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).ToList();

return items[1].Key;
```

Also, why do you start with `0`? You should probably add `1` to dictionary, when it's not already there:

```
else
{
    di.Add(input[i].ToString(), 1);
}
```

**Update**

Just to let you know, it can be easily solved using LINQ:

```
return input.GroupBy(x => x).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count()).ElementAt(1).Key;
```

Comment: I like your answer better, more complete.

Comment: @Marcin awesome first answer..superb..but the last answer is not giving the answer. Moreover, i did not understood it also.

Comment: @user3365810 The `GroupBy(x => x)` operator on a string will give a sequence of groups containing the characters, the `OrderByDescending(x => x.Count())` sorts the list of groups so the largest count is first, then `ElementAt(1)` gives the second item in the sequence - a group containing all instances of the character that occurs second-most-frequently.  You probably want `ElementAt(1).Key` to get the actual character, or `ElementAt(1).Count()` to get the number of those characters in the input.

Comment: @Corey Ah, I missed `Key` at the end. Thanks for your clarification!

Comment: thank you both very much. Can you please tell me from where should I learn LINQ. For this kinds of queries, I searched a lot, but not getting good results. That would be great help.